# js async/await return promise

Tags: javascript, node.js

Doing just a simple function:

```
 async function doAsync() {
 return await "test"
 }

 console.log(doAsync())
```

Output: Promise `{[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending", [[PromiseValue]]: undefined}`

What could be wrong?

Comment: There is nothing wrong, that is exactly what an async function does, it returns a promise

Comment: Nothing is wrong, this is correct, it's a promise. You probably want to read a little about what promises are and how to work with them, before even jumping to async/await. `doAsync().then((result) => console.log(result))`.

Answer (score 3):

`async` functions return a promise.  **Always.**  You must use `.then()` or `await` on that promise to get the value.

```
doAsync().then(val => {
    console.log(val);
});
```

While `async` and `await` sometimes let you write more synchronous-looking code inside the function itself, they don't fundamentally change asynchronous operations into synchronous ones.

An `async` function still returns a promise and the only way to get its value is to use `.then()` or `await` on it.  If you're returning a value up the chain, you will eventually need to use `.then()` to get the value.

See the [MDN description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) for an async function.  Here's a quote:

> **Return value**
>
> A Promise which will be resolved with the value returned by the async function, or rejected with an uncaught exception thrown from within the async function.

Comment: Well,
I thought the main idea of async/wait to return an actual value to a variable.
I used the promises but it doesn't any sense for me then, why would we need async/wait if we have to use promises again.
Thanks

Comment: @chic_cat - I can't really explain what `await` is useful for here in a comment (that's a longer article), but I find it most useful when there are multiple asynchronous functions that you want to run serially within a function.  I'd suggest you read some of the hundreds of tutorials on `async/await` on the web.  It does not turn an async function into a non-async function.  You can't do that in Javascript.

Comment: Ok, gotcha. Thanks!